# why malwares stop them selfs in virtual machins

Tags: security, virtual-machine, malware

the next paragraph is extracted from an article of  [infosecurity](http://www.infosecurity-magazine.com/news/malware-no-longer-avoids-virtual)

> Blockquote
> Around 18% of malware detects virtual machines and stops executing if it arrives on one; however, four out of five malware samples will run on virtual machines, meaning that these systems need regular protection from malware as well.

I don't understand why virus stops if they detect virtual machine ?
is that to avoid being analysed by tools like cukoo or there is another reason ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed this is done to prevent security analysis. However, such prevention becomes more rare, as more and more systems are virtualized and stopping operations would make it impossible for malware to infect the virtualized system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes malwares prevent them self to run on virtual machines so a malware analyst cannot monitor its behavior. Malware author detects the virtual environment in there code and they put checks in their code so that if they found that they are running in a VM then they stop themself to do malicious behavior. These type of malwares also known as polymorphic malwares.